# How to simplify javascript date object?

Tags: javascript

I create this date object:

```
var date = new Date(06, 2016);
```

When I open browser watch to check the created object I see this:

```
Mon Jun 06 2016 12:51:11 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)
```

How can I simplify the above date object to this:

```
2016-06-06
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date I urge you to PLEASE do some research before posting, its utter laziness to add posts like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this...

```
date.toISOString().split("T")[0] // "2016-06-06"
```

Comment: Brilliant idea. :)